# Scrapy is not working properly

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a web content and I am using Scrapy for this. I have already used the tool many times and it always worked well, but now it stopped working for one of the website "https://careers.dexcom.com/search-results".

When you visit this web page you will see there is a "li" with class "jobs-list-item", when I try to grab the data using this selector then it gives nothing.

Here is the code U have tried so far:

```
import scrapy


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'brick_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://careers.dexcom.com/search-results']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.jobs-list-item'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            print "****************here we go****************"
            """
            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 a ::text'
            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            }
            """
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't __do__ anything.  Half of it is commented out with triple-quotes, and anyway all it does is define a class which is never _called_.  Show us the actual code you tried, and its output, and what you expected instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "the page" in context of Scrapy doesn't have "li" with class "jobs-list-item" because it is pure HTML response while list items are loading using Ajax.

To see the page as Scrapy sees it use `scrapy shell http://careers.dexcom.com/search-results` and then enter `view(response)` in console appeared.

To parse jobs feed you need to either use something like [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) (which is overhead in my opinion) or just find Ajax feed URL, request it and parse JSON response.